# How does Google achieve Pod namespacing?

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods

Firebase pods are namespaced with the prefix `pod Firebase/[module-name]`.

How can I build a set of Pods using a similar naming convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase pods (FirebaseFoo) are each dependencies of a similarly named subspec (Foo) in the `Firebase` pod. See the CocoaPods [docs on subspecs](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#subspec) and the [Firebase podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/5.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json) for the details.